# Explicit waits best combinations for click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm wondering what combination of explicit waits will be the best for click method. Currently, I'm using only:

```
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf
```

And I thought it will be better to replace it or combine (add two) with:

```
ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
```

Would it be a good practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not this method is better or this.
There are different elements on different web pages. Some elements are not visible at all so only `presenceOf` expected conditions can be applied on such elements, some are visible but not clickable and some are visible and clickable.
So, if you want to extract a text from element you probably will use `visibilityOf` expected conditions but if you want to click some element `elementToBeClickable` should be used.
Just for additional information: `elementToBeClickable` Selenium method is internally contains `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf` and `isEnabled`.
So, `elementToBeClickable` is actually means element is visible and enabled.
This also means you do not need to combine `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf` and `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` if you want to click the element. `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` is enough since it internally contains `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf` as described.